# react-native-testing-library and styled-components can't access props

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I have a styled-component defined like this :

```
export const StyledButton = styled.TouchableOpacity<IButtonProps>
  height: 46px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: ${EAppColors.BLACK};
  opacity: ${props => (props.disabled ? 0.6 : 1)};
;

interface IButtonProps {
  readonly children: React.ReactNode;
  readonly onPress: () => any;
  readonly style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  readonly testID?: string;
  readonly disabled?: boolean;
}

const Button: React.FC<IButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  style,
  onPress,
  disabled = false,
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      testID={'button.simple'}
      onPress={onPress}
      style={style}
      disabled={disabled}>
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};
```

and I would like with react-native-testing-library to access the disabled props.
There is my test :

```
 const { getByTestId } = render(
      <Button disabled={false} onPress={onPressMock}>
        <Text>Title</Text>
      </Button>,
    );
```

but when I log in my test suite I only have this:

```
  console.log(getByTestId('button.simple').props);
```

And the result of the console.log in my terminal :

```
  {
    accessible: true,
    style: {
      height: 46,
      width: '100%',
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderRadius: 8,
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      opacity: 1
    },
    testID: 'button.simple'
```

How can I access to the props passed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test ?

Comment: @aquinq. I'm trying to test if my component contains in its props: "disabled"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you *really* want to access the prop of your component.
Checking if the correct prop has been passed or not, is more or less equivalent to testing that `react-native` does its job correctly (which is not what you want to test ! But maybe you have a good reason to...).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume what you want to test is if the opacity of your `StyledButton` is indeed `0.6` when it's `disabled`?
If yes, I highly recommend the use of [testing/library/jest-native](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native) and more particularly the [toHaveStyle](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native#tohavestyle) method :

```js
it('sets the correct opacity if disabled', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <Button disabled={true} onPress={onPressMock}>
      <Text>Title</Text>
    </Button>
  );

  const button = getByTestId('button.simple');

  expect(button).toHaveStyle({ opacity: 0.6 });
});
```

Comment: @aquiq for this use case you are right  ;)
 but which is weird is that even if I do an **expect(queryByTestId ('buttonID')). toHaveProp ('disabled')**  or any other props I have **null**